# JavaFx WebView, как увидеть ошибки в консоли

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Использую JavaFx `WebView`, не могу разобраться как увидеть ошибки, которые показываются в консоли браузера, если я открываю страницу через Google Chrome, а в `WebView` как?

Вот так я создаю WebView:

```
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    webView.getEngine().load(url);
});
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить специальный слушатель:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    webView.getEngine().load(url);

    WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webVieww, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
            System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!! помоголо